# Rewarding an existing answer which has not been accepted but already rewarded by others

Tags: support, bounties

I want to reward [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11120593/700926) on StackOverflow with at least 50 points of my rep, however, the answer is not the accepted answer and it has already been rewarded by "Community" - so I'm not quite sure if it is possible for me to do this?

If I choose:

1. Start a Bounty
2. Selects 50 points of my rep.
3. Selects `Reward existing answer`

... then I'm presented with this dialog:

[image]

At this point, I'm not quite sure what will happen if I press "Start Bounty" - will my reward go to the accepted answer right away? Or will it be possible for me to choose which answer to reward?

I'm asking because I won't risk my reward automatically goes to other than the previous mentioned answer.

Thanks.

Comment: You can always award additional bounties. You may be required to set a higher minimum bounty depending on how much bounty was offered in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bounty will only ever be awarded automatically after it has expired (after 7 days + grace period). If you start a bounty you have full control over which answer it is awarded to. You can award it to any existing or new answer other than your own (after the bounty has been active for at least 24 hours).

Your choice of bounty reason is only text,  it does not constrain your choice

Comment: Thanks, you're right :) Now I just have to wait for ~24hrs (?) before the bounty can be rewarded..

Comment: Yes, should probably have mentioned that, you need to wait for at least 24 hours before awarding (still that gives the question greater visibility so may reward the answer over and above the amount you're awarding