# Is there a way to promote a brand new answer to an old question crowded with many outdated answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, old-questions

I'm talking about very good and **old questions** (5 years, 80 000 views) with **many answers** (good and bad ones) but no perfect answer you know.

Ok, nothing special for now.

But... Time goes by and common knowledge + technology increase.
We now have the power to answer the question with an optimal answer and provide the community with a **cutting edge solution**.

The problem is that the question is really crowded with too many answers, too many votes, and a **brand new optimal answer** will never be considered, completely **lost in the crowd**.

Is there a way to get a new (high-quality) answer out of the crowd?

---

*p.s.* : If there is no way, can we think about how to find a way? Like promote the answer in comments? A special feature? The problem is that this kind of action cannot be objective.

*p.p.s.* : I can provide you with a case example on Stack Overflow if you want. But it's **my** answser and then it's not very objective. Let me know.

Comment: Patience? *Over time* the good answers, even late ones, still float up.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214718/rewarding-an-existing-answer-which-has-not-been-accepted-but-already-rewarded-by

Comment: also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101421/how-can-we-prevent-non-optimal-answers-from-being-cemented-to-popular-and-matu?rq=1

Answer (score 11):

You can promote the answer from outside the site. For example, a blog entry can tell the story of how back in 2012 when [link] was asked, there really wasn't a good way to handle things. It can paraphrase the other answers and then -tada!- reveal the exciting new development that enables things to be better now. Folks who follow that link (you can link directly to the answer if you like) will probably be well primed to vote you up. You can do the same thing in less characters on Twitter or whatever - think "New C++14 features mean this old unsolved problem is now solved [link]" or any other platform you have available. No platform? Write a CodeProject article and explain it was inspired by the question, and include the link.

Also, the asker is notified of new answers. If yours really is amazingly great and so much better, the asker may move the tick. This will ensure yours is shown first, so all will know there is now a better way (and chances are they'll upvote if that's what you're about.)

Comment: I love this answer

Answer (score 7):

You can post a bounty on the *question*.  This will indirectly draw attention to the answers, including new ones, which will encourage voting.

A bounty on an old question will often draw extra attention to newer answers, as well (at least it does for me).